# Where is my nancy request waiting?

Tags: c#, nancy

i am trying to avoid nancyfx application, execute same endpoint more than once at a time.

i tried something like below

```
pipelines.BeforeRequest.AddItemToStartOfPipeline(ctx =>
{
    Console.WriteLine("Starting url: " + ctx.Request.Url.ToString());
    if (ExecutingRequests.Instance.AlreadyExecuting(ctx.Request.Url.ToString()))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("bypass " + ctx.Request.Url.ToString());
        var response = new Response();
        response.Headers.Add("bypass", "bypass");
        response.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.RequestTimeout;
        return response;
    }
    ExecutingRequests.Instance.StartRequest(ctx.Request.Url.ToString());
    return null;
});

pipelines.AfterRequest.AddItemToEndOfPipeline(ctx =>
{
    if (!ctx.Response.Headers.ContainsKey("bypass"))
        ExecutingRequests.Instance.EndRequest(ctx.Request.Url.ToString());
});
```

To test behavior i send 2 requests, one after another.

First request adds itself to ExecutionRequests (class only contains thread-safe collection of urls of executing requests) as normal, but when i try to send 2nd request before 1st request is completed and returned response (expecting requesttimeout response immediately), 2nd request waits 20-30 sec,

if 1st request didnt still completed, it give requesttimeout (as expected)
if 2nd request did completed, 2nd requests executes too, where i expect 2nd request to get requesttimeout as soon as i send.

is there some kind of request queue, if so, why 2nd request is queued when there was only 2 requests sent to application.

> Edit: It seems if you send 2nd request to exact same url for action
>   that takes more than 20 seconds. 1st request start executing
>   immediately but 2nd request waits exactly 20 seconds, and than starts
>   executing. Looks like there is some kind of resource pooling

Comment: What happens if you do not have those 2 two handlers in the pipelines? Is there any wait on the second request before it reaches the route?

Comment: I removed all handler, behavior is exactly same, 

Take some action that takes more than 20 seconds. (put sleep or something like that)

Send 1st request to url

Wait for 1-2 secs

Send 2nd url to exact same url, It will only start executing after 20 seconds.

What does application do within this 20 seconds ?

Comment: i think there is some kind of resource pooling, but coulnt figure out how it works

Comment: I think this may be solved by the async feature of nancy.  See here: http://blog.jonathanchannon.com/2013/08/24/async-route-handling-with-nancy/